# Naming (individually) charts exported as images from Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Firstly I have a one routine that creates mulitple charts from individual rows of excel data. This works fine.

I have a second script that exports these multiple charts from the same excel sheet as images to a desktop folder, but I'd like to be able to include a specific name for each chart that is using a cell reference from the data that created it, e.g. a customer reference number (for each exported chart's file name). Below is the code I currently have, but I only currently get the "sheet name chart number" as the file name. I'd like each name to be created from referencing a cell in the specific row of excel data that created it. Possible, please?

```
Sub ExportAllCharts()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objWindowsFolder As Object
    Dim strWindowsFolder As String
    Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objChartObject As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim objChart As Excel.Chart

    'Select a Windows folder
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objWindowsFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a Windows folder:", 0, "")

    If Not objWindowsFolder Is Nothing Then
       strWindowsFolder = objWindowsFolder.self.Path & "\"

       For i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
           Set objSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)

           If objSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
              For Each objChartObject In objSheet.ChartObjects
                  Set objChart = objChartObject.Chart
                  objChart.Export strWindowsFolder & objChart.Name & ".jpg"
              Next
          End If
       Next

       'Open the windows folder
       Shell "Explorer.exe" & " " & strWindowsFolder, vbNormalFocus
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Might need some more details. What specific cell?

Comment: If your data ranges are consistent, and the cell with the intended chart name is located in a particular cell with respect to this range, you can get the data range by parsing a chart SERIES formula, then offset from this to find the intended chart name.